# I have a list that contains pairs of items. I want to compare elements of a pair with elements of another pair?

Tags: python, list, function, sorting, for-loop

connected_disks =[ [0,4], [1,11], [2,0], [0,9], [5,11] ]

In my program each item "says":

disk 0 overlaps with disk 4, disk 1 overlaps with disk 5, and so on.

Since disk 0 overlaps with disk 4 and 1 and 2, this forms a CLUSTER. I want to bring these all together as a single item in the list.
So I want to compare items within the list so that i can create a sorted list which have common elements:

sorted_disks=[ [0,4,2,9], [1,11,5] ] for example.

i have to do this using a function, starting something like this:

def joincluster(c1,c1)
    for c in connected_disks[c2]:
     if c in connected_disks[c1]:

where c1 and c2 are random pairs in the list connected_disks, and c represents a particular element in a pair.

but I need help. Any ideas??

Cheers guys

Comment: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thats a cool link thanks!